# Passing a third argument to sort function of C++(STL)

Tags: c++, stl

Normally compare function of `sort` in c++ takes two arguments e.g:

```
sort(v.begin(),v.end(),compare);

bool compare(int a,int b)
.
.
.
```

But in the vector I have stored an array and I want to `sort` the vector based on a particular index. viz:

```
int arr[3];

vector<arr> v;
```

How can I use sort function if I want to sort v based on index 0 or 1 or 2(depending on user's input)? Here problem is that when I will write compare function:

```
bool compare(int *arr,int *arr1)
```

then how can I tell this function to sort on the basis of a particular index?

Comment: You can't store C-arrays in standard containers...can you show us your real code?

Comment: What do you mean by `sort v based on index 0 or 1 or 2`?

Comment: struct coord

 {

  int *arr;
 };
 vector<coord> v;
Here I want to sort v based on arr's index i.e sometimes I want to sort all objects of type coord using arr[0] or arr[1] or arr[2].

Comment: I adjusted my example based on you coord structure. But that's does not really matter I think you will get the idea.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/List_comprehensions#C.2B.2B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use functor object:

```
struct coord { int *arr; };
struct Comparer : std::binary_function<coord,coord,bool> {
    Comparer( int base ) : m_base( base ) {}
    bool operator()( const coord &c1, const coord &c1 ) 
    { 
        return c1.arr[m_base] < c2.arr[m_base]; 
    }
private:
    int m_base;
};
//...
std::sort( v.begin(), v.end(), Comparer( 1 ) );
```

Comment: In c++11 this is even cleaner with lambdas.

Comment: Your Comparer class should extend std::binary_function.