# Passing a member function with two parameters to C++ STL algorithm stable_partition

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

I have member functions as follows

```
class foo 
{
    public:
        ...
        bool isNotEqualId(const Agent&, const int);
        std::vector<Agent> foo::extractAgents(int id);
    private:
        std::vector<Agent> agents;
}
```

The function definition is below:

```
bool foo::isNotEqualId(const Agent& agent, const int id)
{
    return (agent.groupId != id);
}
```

Now, within foo, I am partitioning agents given the agent ID, in order to extract them given another parameter later on.

```
std::vector<Agent>& foo::extractAgents(int id)
{
    std::vector<Agent>::iterator iter = std::stable_partition(agents.begin(), agents.end(), &foo::isNotEqualId(id));

    // Partition to find agents that need to be removed
    std::vector<Agent>::iterator extractedGroupiter = std::stable_partition(iter, agents.end(), keepAgent);
    // Create a vector with the agents that need to be removed
    std::vector<Agent> extractedGroup(extractedGroupiter, agents.end());
    // Erase them from the agents vector
        agents.erase(extractedGroupiter, agents.end());
        return extractedGroup;
}
```

using `std::stable_partition` used to work when used with functions that had a fixed group value, such as

```
bool isNotGroup0(const Agent& a)
{
    return a.groupId != 0;
}
```

However, now I want to use a member function that takes in two parameters, so the group ID can be a parameter. `stable_partition` takes in a unary predicate which is causing me the issue. I've tried using `std::bind2nd` with `std::mem_fun` in order to bind the 2nd parameter when passing it to `stable_partition`, but it results in errors with `mem_fun` having no instance of the overloaded function.

I've also tried a functor solution such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055606/passing-a-third-argument-to-sort-function-of-cstl?rq=1), which suggests using a `std::binary_function`, however it understandably results in an error of `term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments`. I'm using VS2010. Any Pointers?

Comment: an other question: why are you writing the class name in this line std::vector<Agent> foo::extractAgents(int id);

Comment: `bool foo::isNotEqualId(const Agent&, const int id)` is missing identifier, probably agent. Is it a typo ? What error do you get ?

Comment: yes, that's a typo, just updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Visual Studio 2010, and I don't know if lambdas are available in that version, use a function object:

```
struct AgentFunctor
{
   int id_;
   AgentFunctor(int id) : id_(id) {}
   bool operator()(const Agent& agent) const
   { return agent.groupId != id_; }
};
//...
AgentFunctor af(id);
std::vector<Agent>::iterator iter = std::stable_partition(agents.begin(), agents.end(), af);
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, it doesn't have lambdas, and thanks a bunch, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
std::stable_partition(agents.begin(), agents.end(),
                      [nGroupID, foo](x){
                        return foo.isNotEqualID(x, nGroupID);});
```

Just noticed the VS2010 comment, which I'm pretty sure doesn't have lambdas, in which case you have to create the function object more manually, such as in PaulMcKenzie's answer.